# inject $http to angularjs directive es6

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, es6-class

How can I inject $http to the modal directive using es6? I Tried do it like this but I get $http = undefined. At finally i'm trying vcRecaptchaService but have same problem.

```
class ModalDirective {
    /**
     * Constructor class ModalDirective
     */
    constructor($http) {
        this.restrict = 'E',
        this.scope = {
            show: '=',
            subm: '=',
            emailState: '=',
            requestResult: '='
        },
            this.transclude = true,
        this.template = require('./modal.tpl.html');
        this.$http = $http


    }

    link(scope, attrs) {
        scope.dialogStyle = {};
        scope.formData = {};


        scope.hideModal = function() {
            scope.show = false;
        };

     console.log(this.$http);

    }
 }
 export default ModalDirective;
```

Comment: use "ngInject" gulp or equivalent in your build system

Comment: look into this https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter it might help

Answer (score 2):

To inject `$http` into an ES6 class AngularJS directive, use [`$inject` Property Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation):

```js
class myDirective {
  constructor ($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
  }
  link(scope, elem, attrs) {
    console.log(this.$http);
  }
}
myDirective.$inject = ["$http"];

angular.module("app",[])
.directive("myDirective", myDirective);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app=app>
    <h1>ES6 Directive Example</h1>
    <div my-directive></div>
  </body>
```

See also [ToddMoto: AngularJS styleguide (ES2015)](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#angularjs-styleguide-es2015)

Comment: If I do it like you sad , I get $http = undefined.

Comment: The above Demo works. What are you doing differently than the above Demo?

Comment: Maybe something wrong in my modules imort file ?
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZTwRL1E6hC5gwBPpjzAt?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function which returns an instance of your class:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('modal', ['$http', $http => new ModalDirective($http)]);
```

Comment: ES6 features (such as classes and arrow functions) are now all possible with AngularJS 1.5.

Comment: @georgeawg I had no idea you could pass a class directly to `.directive` now. Good to know!